# Creating Typescript definition file for timer-machine

Tags: typescript

We are using the following javascript library in our project:

[timer-machine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timer-machine)

I tried the following definition:

```
//timer-machine.d.ts

declare module "timer-machine" {
  export class Timer{}
}
```

inside the application I tried to use it in the following way:

```
import {Timer} from "timer-machine";
...
let timer = new Timer()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _timerMachine.Timer is not a constructor
```

How exactly can I modify my definition that I can at least instatiate a timer like it is described in the description for the library?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the basic usage:

```
var Timer = require('timer-machine')
var myTimer = new Timer()
```

You can see that *Timer* should be at the *root*. So:

```
//timer-machine.d.ts

declare module "timer-machine" {
  class Timer{}
  export = Timer;
}
```